# IRAF imalign will not shift images, incorrectly reports unequal number of input and output images, why?

Tags: astronomy, fits, iraf

I recently started working in IRAF as I have the need for image data reduction. 
I tried to stack .fit images using imalign function, but I get this error message:

[image]

This was a test, so I have only 4 images in input and output lists, and I have 4 shifts in shiftlist.txt. These are my files - input list:

```
NGC7286-0001_B.fit
NGC7286-0003_B.fit
NGC7286-0004_B.fit
NGC7286-0005_B.fit
```

Output list:

```
sh-NGC7286-0001_B.fit
sh-NGC7286-0003_B.fit
sh-NGC7286-0004_B.fit
sh-NGC7286-0005_B.fit
```

Shiftlist:

```
0.0 0.0
3.751 4.55
3.997 9.273
3.107 15.243
```

List of coordinates of referent stars:

```
618.58 666.96
1136.19 711.39
1288.88 942.79
1417.72 927.84
1004.71 1517.73
1053.39 1756.91
532.16 1794.60
```

Why do I get this error message? Do you see anything wrong with my files?
If I use shiftlist I calculated, do I need to change bigbox (20) and/or boxsize (7)? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, though I don't know why my IRAF have that problem.
I can't have "_" character in the names of my images.
Strange, but now aligning works I guess.